# Button to go BACK in application

Tags: android, back-button, android-2.3-gingerbread

I need to code a button to go BACK to the main application activity.

```
public void onGotoMainActivity(View View)
    {
         Intent intent = new Intent(View.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
         this.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The Main activity is already started and has not been destroyed. So I don't think this would be a "new" intent nor should it "start activity"? Shouldn't it merely call the main activity back to focus?

Answer (score 1):

you should set `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` so instead of launching a new instance of the `Activity` it will clear all `Activities` on the top of the stack and deliver  the intent to (on top now) `Activity` with a new `Intent`

```
public void onGotoMainActivity(View View)
    {
         Intent intent = new Intent(View.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         this.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Like this?

public void onGotoLatePassActivity(View View)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(View.getContext(), LatePassActivity.class);
        
         intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
         this.startActivity(intent);
         
    }

LatePassActivity is my main activity class

This code still makes the app crash unexpectedly.

Comment: You should use: Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LatePassActivity.class);

Answer (score 1):

You can use this also.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

just use `finish()` in the `onClick()`

or add this if you're more than 1 activity in

```
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to simulate a back button?

```
dispatchKeyevent(Keyevent.ACTION_DOWN, Keyevent.BUTTON_BACK);
dispatchKeyevent(Keyevent.ACTION_UP, Keyevent.BUTTON_BACK);
```

Answer (score 0):

This cleared it all up for me.

```
public void onGotoMainActiviy(View View)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(View.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    CurrentActivity.this.finish();
}
```

Thank you everyone for getting me on the right track. The activities' life cycle was defiantly valuable information.